# Should I use httpd.conf or apache2.conf for Apache configuration?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, http

On Ubuntu, I am trying to get the `httpd.conf` file for apache2. My server does not show one.

Would `apache2.conf` be the same as `httpd.conf`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just did some more research on this (beyond my comment):

> [Ubuntu Docs: HTTPD - Apache2 Web Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/httpd.html)
> **apache2.conf**: the main Apache2 configuration file. Contains settings that are global to Apache2.
>
> **httpd.conf**: historically the main Apache2 configuration file, named after the httpd daemon. The file can be used for user specific configuration options that globally effect Apache2.

So to echo @slhck - I would source the `httpd.conf` from the `apache2.conf`.

Answer (score 12):

`httpd.conf` is empty (or nonexistent) in some distributions. If an `apache2.conf` is present you should probably not edit this, but include your own `httpd.conf` from the `apache2.conf`. This is because `apache2.conf` may be overwritten by package updates.

Your `apache2.conf` therefore should include this line. If it doesn't already, you can add it yourself:

```
Include httpd.conf
```

`/etc/apache2/conf.d` is also a good place to put configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

The sites-available method is generally considered the "Debian Way":
•   "main" config in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
•   "user" config in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
•   vhosts in /etc/apache2/sites-available files (one per file, typically)
•   you might want to number them, e.g. 00-domain.com, 01-otherdomain.com
•   ports (Listen directives) in /etc/apache2/ports.conf
•   mods in /etc/apache2/mods-available

You can manipulate these with symlinks or with the a2 series of commands:
a2ensite/a2dissite 
a2enmod/a2dismod

Depending on personal preference, you can restart Apache using apachectl, /etc/init.d/apache2 (start|stop|reload|restart), or service apache2 (start|stop|reload|restart)

An example where you would use httpd.conf instead of a vhost entry would be for a global redirect or rewrite rule, for example. Other tidbits -- generally, you should leave apache2.conf alone, and make sure you set up a consistent naming scheme for vhosts in the sites-available directory.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/216260/366148

Answer (score 0):

The install of apache2 on my Ubuntu server has a folder `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` in which all the configuration files belong. The default one is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and there are others for subdomains. I have no httpd.conf

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1128496)